# graphicsmagick 1.3.16 how to conver all pages?

Tags: graphicsmagick

with gm 1.3.12 its easy

```
gm convert pdf:in.pdf jpeg:out.jpeg
```

results in

```
out.jpeg.0
out.jpeg.1
out.jpeg.2 
etc..
```

with 1.3.16

```
gm convert pdf:in.pdf jpeg:out.jpeg
```

generate out.jpeg only (1st page from in.pdf)

```
gm convert pdf:in.pdf[2] jpeg:out.jpeg
```

e.g. nicely outputs 2nd page from pdf.

despite heavy searching I cannot seem to find how make 1.3.16 gm output all pages from pdf with one single command ( as it works in 1.3.12 ).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this command:

```
gm convert pdf:in.pdf +adjoin jpeg:out.jpeg.%01d
```

(tested with GraphicsMagick 1.3.18)